# send image to server by passing datURL generated from canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html5-canvas

I tried to save canvas image to '~/image/upload' folder in my application. I get this error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed). What am I doing wrong here?

```
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "image/upload",
data: { 
        imgBase64: dataURL
    }
}).done(function(o) {
   console.log('saved');                                                                     
});
```

Comment: It (probably) means your server-side application doesn't allow a POST requestfor the URL `image/upload`. So the problem (probably) isn't in your JS code, but in the server-side code. (ou probably do want to use `/image/upload`, though).

Answer (score 0):

Probably URL need to be escaped

```
var dataURL = encodeURIComponent(canvas.toDataUrl());
```

Comment: I still get the same error. Do I need to add anything in my url?

Comment: hmm. what if to add `contentType: "application/json"` as ajax param. If it's not work definetely need to check backend method "image/upload"